# How many RAM does Eclipse CHE use for itself?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-che

For whom have installed Eclipse Che. Did you have a look at the RAM usage of the core system ? I mean, before starting to code ?

Answer (score 1):

See [What are the minimum requirements to run an Eclipse Che server for 1 user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933321/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-to-run-an-eclipse-che-server-for-1-user)

I personally run Minishift on Windows 10 in order to play with Red Hat CodeReady Workspaces 1.0.1 (the product version of Che 6.x). I recommend giving minishift 6GB of ram, if you can spare it.

Answer (score 1):

The resource requirements are detailed in the [Che documentation admin guide](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-6/openshift-admin-guide.html).

For a multi-user Che deployment, there are 3 containers, which require RAM and storage space for persistent volumes. The absolute minimum resources are:

- Che workspace server: 750MB of RAM, 1GB of disk in a PVC
- Keycloak: 1GB of RAM, 2 PVCs, 1GB each
- PostgreSQL: ~515MB of RAM, 1GB PVC for the database

So just to run the workspace server, you will need about 3GB of RAM and 4GB of persistent storage.

In addition, workspaces will need ~2GB of RAM each (requirements change based on language runtime and developer tools). Workspaces can use ephemeral storage or persistent storage for source code and work. If using ephemeral storage, you will need to commit your work before the workspace is stopped or auto-suspended. If using persistent storage, you can use one large PVC which is shared by all workspaces, or a separate PVC per workspace (which may take more storage resources, and makes right-sizing more difficult).