# What are the minimum requirements to run an Eclipse Che server for 1 user?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-che

I like the features of Codenvy but the sever is too long to wake up and can't be used from a mobile. Yes, I code in the subway for hobbies. I had in the idea to install it on a small VPS. I will be coding a Django site roughly the same size as a small eShop. What would be the minimal requirement for the server to run it smoothly?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Minishift I suggest granting it at least 6GB of RAM.

```
minishift config set memory 6G
```

For more information, see the [Eclipse Che admin guide](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-6/openshift-admin-guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

See Eclipse Che documentation - [Single-User: Installation on Docker](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-6/docker-single-user.html):

> Minimum one CPU, 2GB of RAM, 3GB disk space.